# How to search between two dates in LINQ to Entity?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have an example in SQL how to use the same logic in Linq to Entity?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEN STARTDATE AND ENDDATE
```

Answer (score 42):

I'm assuming C#.

```
DateTime startDate=bla;
DateTime endDate=blabla;
using(var db=new MyDataContext())
{
    var filteredData=db.TABLE.Where(t => t.DATE > startDate && t.DATE < endDate);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Use `>=` and `<=` to give the same results as `BETWEEN`, though.

Comment: I never use BETWEEN for exactly this reason. I prefer the explicitness of the other form.

Comment: For me this didn't worked got LINQ to Entity error. I am also using DBContext

Comment: @CraigStuntz Even adding `=` skipping all the records for `endDate`. Can u guess..? why does this happen..?

Comment: @shashwat To actually get the values between the two dates, I think you actually would want `t.DATE >= startDate && t.DATE < endDate`, where `endDate` has had an extra day added to it. Otherwise you won't get anything for the last date (because a date is actually 12am on that day, so less than or equal to 12am some date does not actually get anything during it, only before it.)

Comment: Thanks @Sahuagin. I've switched fromo .NET to NodeJs now. But I believe that would work for sure. Anyway, appreciate your response even after almost 2.5 yr. :D

Comment: there will be small issue if the Date is CurrentDate and Time is 12:00 and Record is made before that.. in that Case.. no records are retrieved

Answer (score 18):

You will want it to be inclusive on the start date, but *exclusive* on the end date. This is because a `DateTime` used as a date is really the very beginning of that day, and doesn't extend to the end of the day.

```
// dates that are inclusive on the date range
var startDate = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1);
var endDate = new DateTime(2016, 12, 31);

...

// WRONG: this will ignore data on the last day
.Where(obj => obj.StartDate >= startDate && obj.EndDate <= endDate)

// RIGHT: this will include the last day
var endDateExclusive = endDate.AddDays(1);

...

.Where(obj => obj.StartDate >= startDate && obj.EndDate < endDateExclusive)
```

Even if you are using specific `DateTime` values, it can still be important to use `>=` and `<`, rather than `>=` and `<=` or `>` and `<`.

If you use both `>=` and `<=` signs, then two date ranges from X to Y and from Y to Z would both include records that exactly match Y. Depending on your requirements it could be a serious flaw to include the record in both date ranges. Similarly, if you use `>` and `<`, you would instead *exclude* records from both date ranges that exactly matched Y.

Comment: Adding a whole day may cause some unexpected problems and it sounds like a code smell to me. The fact is that when you search between dates, most times you will want to search from the first second of the start date to the last second of the end date. Example: from "2020-12-20 00:00:00.000" to "2020-12-20 23:59:59.999" to search for an entire day.

Comment: @leoap you could do it by constructing a "2020-12-20 23:59:59.999" end date DateTime value, yes, but searching < 2020-12-21 has the same effect and makes more sense if you're just dealing with dates and not times. The correct search is `startDate >= 2020-12-20 && endDate < 2020-12-21`, which finds data on the one day. note the endDate is then exclusive not inclusive.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but the point of my comment is about the action of adding a whole day to the date, not the comparison method itself. If it happens that a date is "2020-12-20 03:45:57", then adding a whole day will cause it to be "2020-12-21 03:45:57", and it may cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: @leoap ok but what you're saying is basically that if the start timestamp has an unexpected time value, then the end timestamp would too. sure, if you compute from wrong data, you end up with wrong data. the point is to end up with a "date" datetime value for the end date. creating a datetime for exactly "2020-12-21 0:00:00" wouldn't make your example any more correct. in my example I created a new DateTime and then added 1 day to it, which will not have any unexpected time value. (in my own code I actually use a custom Date struct anyway.)

Comment: If you always create the date object, ok. but if the date comes from another source, its dangerous to just add a whole day. that's what i'm saying.